# Ошибка "еnd() iterator not dereferencablе"

Tags: c++

При попытке запустить этот код возникает ошибка: `end() iterator not dereferencable`. Что не так в коде и в логике?

```
// store_credit@google-code-jam.cpp
//

/*
Qualification Round Africa 2010
Problem A

You receive a credit C at a local store and would like to buy two items. 
You first walk through the store and create a list L of all available items. 
From this list you would like to buy two items that add up to the entire value of the credit. 
The solution you provide will consist of the two integers 
indicating the positions of the items in your list (smaller number first).

*/

//#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

/*

Limits

5 ≤ C ≤ 1000
1 ≤ P ≤ 1000

Small dataset

N = 10
3 ≤ I ≤ 100

Large dataset

N = 50
3 ≤ I ≤ 2000

*/

int main()
{

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            /*Input

            The first line of input gives the number of cases, N.N test cases follow.*/
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    int N;
    cout << "Specify the number of cases " << endl;
    cin >> N; 
    if (N < 0 || N > 50) cerr << "Too many cases: " << N;

                /*
                For each test case there will be:
                */
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {

        int C,I;
        cin >> C;       //One line containing the value C, the amount of credit you have at the store.
        if ( C <5 || C > 1000) cerr << "Credit out of limits:" << C;
        cout << '\n';
        cin >> I;       //One line containing the value I, the number of items in the store.
        if ( I <3 || C > 2000) cerr << "Number of items out of limits:" << I;
        cout << '\n';

        // assume everything is all right at this point
        // let's build a hash table

        unordered_multimap <int,int> prices;
        int* buffer =new int[I];
        for (int j = 0; j < I; j++) // possibly j <I-1
        {

            cin >> buffer[j];       //One line containing a space separated list of I integers. 
                                    //Each integer P indicates the price of an item in the store.
            if(buffer[j] < 1 || buffer[j] > 1000) cerr << "Price inadequate: " << prices[j];
            prices.insert(make_pair(buffer[j],j));
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < I; j++)
        {
            cout << buffer[j]<<" "; 
        }
        cout << "\n";

        for (auto iter = prices.begin(); iter != prices.end(); ++iter)
        {
            cout << "{" << (*iter).first << "," << (*iter).second << "},  ";
        }

        //Each test case will have exactly one solution.
        for(auto iter = prices.begin(); iter != prices.end(); ++iter)
        {
            int w =  (*iter).second;
            if (prices.find(C- w)->second != w ) cout << "Found it: pair (" << w << "," << prices.find(C-w)->second << ") has a sum of " << C <<endl; 
            //вот тут я недодумал
        }

        //Each test case will have exactly one solution.
        for(int j = 0; j < I-1; j++)
        {

            int w =  prices.find(C-buffer[j])->second;
            if(prices.count(C-buffer[j]) > 0  && (j < w) ) cout << "Found it: pair (" << j << "," << w << ") has a sum of " << C <<endl;

        }

        //Output

        // For each test case, output one line containing "Case #x: " 
        // followed by the indices of the two items whose price adds up to the store credit.
        // The lower index should be output first.

        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            cout << "Case #" << i << endl; 
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы бы указали строчку, в которой происходит ошибка.

Хотя вообще-то всё понятно из сообщения об ошибке: вы разыменовываете итератор, который показывает за границу массива.

Comment: Я и указал, большими буквами в комментарии. Из сообщения об ошибке понятно, что происходит, а я бы хотел знать, почему.

Comment: Хм, а как это у вас вообще компилируется? У меня компилятор ругается на индексирование `unordered_muiltimap`: http://ideone.com/vd2IjB (да и в [документации](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap) `operator[]` не упомянут).

Comment: У меня это компилируется под MS Visual Studio 2012. Но `[]` да, не упомянут. А вот для `unordered_map` он есть: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/operator%5B%5D/

Comment: Очень странно. У меня на коде с ideone VS 2012 выдаёт вот что: http://pastebin.com/nd0sPGhS

---
Угу, для `unordered_map` он есть, но у вас ведь `multimap`.

Comment: Хорошо, какое следствие из этого Вы хотите обсудить? Код не должен компилироваться? Код можно поправить? Именно из-за этого код выдаёт ошибку?

Comment: Ещё раз: ваш код у меня не компилируется, ни с VS 2012, ни с gcc. Поскольку вы говорите, что ошибка возникает при запуске программы (то есть, что у вас код компилируется), то либо вы опубликовали не тот код, о котором говорите, либо вы над нами прикалываетесь.

Answer (score 3):

Я смотрю вы смело делаете в вашем коде такие вещи как

```
prices.find(C- w)->second
```

По-видимому один из ваших вызовов `prices.find(...)` заканчивается "провалом", т.е. искомый ключ не находится в `prices`. В такой ситуации `prices.find()` возвращает `prices.end()`, а попытка применения оператора `->` к таком итератору и приводит к вышепроцитированной ошибке времени выполнения.

---

Отдельно стоит обратить внимание на сомнительную практику делать

```
prices.insert(make_pair(buffer[j],j));
```

Такой `make_pair` генерирует временный объект типа  `std::pair<int, int>`. А в `std::unordered_multimap<int, int>` на самом деле хранятся пары `std::pair<const int, int>`. Это - разные типы. `std::pair` разных типов умеют неявно преобразовываться друг к другу, т.е. код спокойно компилируется. Но на самом деле в данном случае после вызова `std::make_pair` производится еще и неявное преобразование `std::pair<int, int>` в `std::pair<const int, int>`, на которое может бессмысленно тратиться время (зависит от версии языка и оптимизационных способностей компилятора).

Разумнее поступать так:

```
prices.insert(unordered_multimap<int, int>::value_type(buffer[j], j));
```

или, в С++11, вообще просто так

```
prices.insert({ buffer[j], j });
```

Это гарантирует точное совпадение типа и исключает лишнее преобразование.

Comment: по Вашему `prices.insert(unordered_multimap<int, int>::value_type(buffer[j], j));` - достойно написания? Готов спорить, что `prices.insert(make_pair(buffer[j],j));` не проиграет ни в одном тесте сколь бы то ни было значимое время. Кстати, в C++11 лучше бы было писать:`prices.emplace(buffer[j],  j );`

Comment: @ixSci: Я лишь иллюстрирую принцип. А для "достойно написания" надо было бы завести `typedef std::unordered_map<int, int> TPricesMap;` и использовать его повсеместно. Тогда получаем `prices.insert(TPricesMap::value_type(buffer[j], j));` и это уже, без вопросов, не просто "достойно написания", а является единственно правильным вариантом. В рамках С++03 эффект от этого может варьироваться от незначительного до астрономического. В C++11 же это, разумеется, является чисто академическим вопросом, ибо С++11 предоставляет существенно более элегантные варианты.

Comment: ни разу я не видел, чтобы кто-то использовал `value_type` вместо `make_pair`. Это чисто академическое решение. Не будет там никакой существенной разницы, тем более астрономической. Лично мне не нравится в ответе комментарий про "сомнительную практику". Она ничуть не сомнительная, а вполне себе устоявшаяся.

Comment: @ixSci : Когда я говорю о размере эффекта, я имею в виду общий случай, а не пару `<int, int>`, в рамках именно С++03 и ранее (которые не имеют move semantics). В общем случае стоимость лишнего *копирования*, разумеется, может быть сколь угодно большой (астрономической) по совершенно очевидным причинам. Что же касается "ни разу не видел"... Ну что я тут могу сказать... Во-первых, мало кто умеет замечать такие тонкости. Во-вторых, В некритическом к производительности коде это зачастую просто не замечают, ибо "и так работает".

Comment: А современные компиляторы С++11 и позже просто скрадывают негативный эффект от такого несоответствия типов через неявное применение move semantics. Однако если используется самописный тяжелый класс, не поддерживающий move, то негативный эффект запросто может стать астрономическим и в С++11.

Comment: да, в общем случае согласен, что-то я зациклился на простых типах.

Answer (score 1):

вам компилятор прямо говорит что End() нельзя разыменовывать!

Описание `vector.end()`[ru](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/end) [en](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/end/) как видно из описания енд возвращает итератор **следующий за последним элементом**

---

тоесть если есть массив `int M[5];` то

- можно вызывать
     `M[0],M[1],M[2],M[3],M[4]` (`M[4]` - возвращает последний элемент)
     элемент
- а функция енд возвращает `M[5]` -
     следующий за последним

Comment: Мне компилятор прямо говорит `expression: list iterator not dereferencable`; Вы уверены, что разбирательство с `vector.end` мне поможет?

Comment: поможет с чём?

Comment: С понимаем проблем в логике моего кода.

Comment: Логика вот этого

    cout << prices[buffer[j]] << " ";

проста. cout **не умеет** работать  с итераторами списка.

Т.е. делаете ручками (в циклк for(multimap<int,int>::iterator i = ...))

Comment: Сделал уже. Теперь думаю, как условие проверки переписать, используя итераторы.